# How to prove an expression including Bessel function is positive?

Tags: inequality, special-functions, bessel-functions

The modified Bessel function of order n of the first kind is given by

$$I_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{2}x)^{2m+n}}{m!\Gamma(m+n+1)}$$

where $\Gamma$ is defined by an improper integral,

$$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Now, how can I prove the following expression is true for all non-zero real value of $\alpha$?

$$\frac{\alpha I_n^\prime(\alpha)}{I_n(\alpha)}>0$$

where $n\geqslant0$ and $n$ is an integer, $I_n^\prime(\alpha)=\frac{dI_n(\alpha)}{d\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{R}^+$, $I_n(x)$ is a convergent series of non-negative, increasing functions. It follows that $I_n(x)$ is positive and increasing over $\mathbb{R}^+$, so $\log(I_n(x))$ is increasing, too, and:
$$\forall x>0,\qquad \frac{d}{dx}\log I_n(x) = \frac{I_n'(x)}{I_n(x)}> 0.$$
Can you complete the proof by studying the behaviour of $I_n(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}^-$ in a similar way?

Comment: @ Jack D' Aurizio, Thanks a lot! The modified Bessel function of the first kind can be also written as $I_n(x)=(\frac{1}{2}x)^n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{2}x)^{2m}}{m!\Gamma(m+n+1)}$. Thus its series part is even function...then? I have a question that why all the textbooks just give the **(modified) Bessel function** on $[0, \infty)$ but not the other half. In addition, there might be a minor mistake in your answer: $I_n(x)$ should be **positive** with $x>0$ instead of **non-negative** :)